# rails4, how to passing all parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Export Data to XLS

and

```
def export_report
  require 'csv'
  @call_requests = CallRequest.reorder("created_at desc")
  @call_requests = @call_requests.where(:device=> params[:device]) if params[:device].present?
  @call_requests = @call_requests.where(:status => params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  .....
end
```

I'll passing many parameter (9~10's parameter)

```
<%= link_to export_report_admin_call_requests_path(device: params[:device], status: parmas[:status], ......format: "xls") do %>
    Export Report
<% end %>
```

It's so long to passing all parameter

passing all parameter is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to merge the `format` data to the `params`.

```
<%= link_to export_report_admin_call_requests_path(params.merge(format: 'xls')) do %>
    Export Report
<% end %>
```